# Flutter fails to run

Tags: android, flutter

I've created a new flutter project and it works just fine with the counter on the android, but when I paste in my old code and dependencies and stuff (works just fine on iPhone) it stops working and gives these errors:

Before pasting in my code:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
D/FlutterActivity(21443): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(21443): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(21443): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(21443): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
D/FlutterView(21443): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@18ff028
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(21443): Executing Dart entrypoint: main, and sending initial route: /
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation(21443): eglMakeCurrent: 0xda51a120: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xda50f060)
D/eglCodecCommon(21443): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
I/Choreographer(21443): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/eglCodecCommon(21443): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
```

After pasting in my code:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.5.6+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/CameraPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.10/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.10/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-5.0.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseanalytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.1+5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.9.3+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemlvision/FirebaseMlVisionPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite-1.0.4/android/src/main/java/sq/flutter/tflite/TflitePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
D/FlutterActivity(21332): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(21332): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(21332): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
W/FlutterEngine(21332): Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@2811b43) but could not find and invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(21332): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:55432/mvn7DG4XGhA=/ws
 If you are using an emulator running Android Q Beta, consider using an emulator running API level 29 or lower.
Learn more about the status of this issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132325318.
```

The project where I copied the files from works on both emulators just fine but when I made a new project (to set a folder structure, clean code, etc) and copy the files in it stops working on the android. I couldn't find an answer to this.

Visually, it launches the launch screen from xml, then it crashes before it actually loads the app welcome screen.

Also what's with the firebase errors, is that normal or something I have to fix?

Installed on a new emulator and this happened:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.10/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.12.10/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.5.6+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camera/CameraPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-5.0.6/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebaseanalytics/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.1+5/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/core/FirebaseCorePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_ml_vision-0.9.3+3/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemlvision/FirebaseMlVisionPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /Users/mohd/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite-1.0.4/android/src/main/java/sq/flutter/tflite/TflitePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk...
D/FlutterActivity( 6892): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 6892): Setting up FlutterEngine.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 6892): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
Flutter is taking longer than expected to report its views. Still trying...
W/FlutterEngine( 6892): Tried to automatically register plugins with FlutterEngine (io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@76b1d2f) but could not find and invoke the GeneratedPluginRegistrant.
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 6892): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
D/AndroidRuntime( 6892): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892): Process: world.dost.dostapp, PID: 6892
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{world.dost.dostapp/world.dost.dostapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The new embedding does not support the old FlutterView.
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The new embedding does not support the old FlutterView.
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.shim.ShimRegistrar.view(ShimRegistrar.java:82)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.WebViewFlutterPlugin.registerWith(WebViewFlutterPlugin.java:17)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:33)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at world.dost.dostapp.MainActivity.configureFlutterEngine(MainActivity.kt:10)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:185)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:418)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6892):    ... 11 more
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/Process ( 6892): Sending signal. PID: 6892 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Could not update files on device: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:59197/upteHOWzeD8=/
```

NOTE: I feel like it's coming from one of the dependencies because when I added just the dependencies in to the project and get and ran the app it crashed with the same errors. So it's probably coming from a dependency.

Comment: what api version is your android emulator/device

Comment: API29, I don't know if that's the issue because the app works just fine from the old project

Comment: The starter counter project works just fine, but when i add the dependencies and files this is what happens.

Comment: `Error connecting to the service protocol: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:55432/mvn7DG4XGhA=/ws
 If you are using an emulator running Android Q Beta, consider using an emulator running API level 29 or lower.` that explains this.. try using api 28

Answer (score 5):

I got the same issue, after running `flutter upgrade; flutter pub upgrade`, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after testing every dependency one by one I found out that [webview_flutter:](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) is not supported on the latest flutter version I think, or not really too sure. After replacing it with [flutter_native_web:](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_web) everything now works just fine. Had nothing to do with firebase files or api version, or etc it was just that...

Comment: how do you testing every dependencies btw

Answer (score 0):

**For proxy problems, follow these instructions!**

Add NO_PROXY with value 127.0.0.1 for your system variables.

[image]

Then, add for your gradle.properties the values **(YOUR_PROJECT/android/gradle.properties)**:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost
systemProp.https.proxyHost=localhost
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3128
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

Now, close your IDE and Emulator/App and open them again.